# How do I show a view over the tab bar but not over the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I want to present a modal view that shows over the `UITabBar` but not over the `UINavigationBar`.

From what I understand the best way to overlay a view on top of everything is to position it in its own `UIWindow`. This works great, and if I make the y origin of the view in the window lower than the navigation bar it works perfectly.

However, getting it lower than that y origin is really hard. I can use the `topLayoutGuide.length` property to position the y, but when I rotate that no longer is true as the navigation bar height changes.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: if you dont want to add overlay then you can present your viewcontroller using navigation controller. so navigation bar will not hide.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani It's a simple view, I'm not interested in adding that level of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with something similar recently, and ultimately to modally present a new view you'll be looking to call the navigation controller and then set its `setDefinesPresentationContext:` to `Yes`.

`setDefinesPresentationContext:` is needed so that a presenting view controller will restrict the bounds of a presented view to the visible area of the presenting view. As a result, the view controller is kept within the bounds of the currently visible window (The default is no, in which case the presented view keeps asking for a defining context up through the VC hierarchy until it reaches a VC that claims this role, or until it hits the UIWindow).

With this method, you won't have to calculate the bounds of your view, it'll just be done automagically. Check out the Apple docs on this method for the full explanation though.

---

(and shameless plug, I wrote about it on [my blog](http://catthoughts.ghost.io/zq-league-of-blargl-day-2/). it's under "Presenting the Search Bar".. pardon the formatting, still a work in progress)